# ContentProvider classnotfound after using Proguard

Tags: android, maven, proguard

I've got this provider defined in `Manifest`.

```
    <provider
        android:name="com.jon.aqclient.sync.StubProvider"
        android:authorities="com.jon.aqclient.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:syncable="true" />
```

The app package is `com.jon.aqclient`, and the `class` is inside *sync package*, so the `class` is in `com.jon.aqclient.sync.StubProvider`. I had the application running perfectly, but after trying `Proguard` for the first time and *mavenizing* the project it crashes with a `classnotfoundexception`.

I've de-mavenized the project, I tried with -keep **`public class com.jon.aqclient.sync`**, and now commenting the `Proguard` line in the `project.properties` file as follows.

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
# proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

I've cleaned the project and nothing. And a strange thing is that if I change the provider definition in `Manifest` to `StubProviderNew`, without any other change, the `error` is the same, `classnotfoundexception` `com.jon.aqclient.sync.StubProvider`, and not `StubProviderNew`.

Where is the project reading that class name? How can I clear totally these?

Please help!

EDIT:

Stack trace:

```
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.jon.aqclient.sync.StubProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jon.aqclient.sync.StubProvider in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/com.jon.aqclient-2.apk]
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3709)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3461)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3417)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:977)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jon.aqclient.sync.StubProvider in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/com.jon.aqclient-2.apk]
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3694)
03-12 15:04:56.259: E/AndroidRuntime(7506):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Try changing the authorities attribute to "com.jon.aqclient.StubProvider"

Comment: You might want to post the full stack trace.

Comment: Done CommonsWare, there it is the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Pff, I've solved it. It was a Maven thing. I didn't know if was Maven or Proguard, but it where the main changes I did before the error appeared.

Maven changed the default output folder to target/... and not bo bin/classes... so the device couldn't find the classes.

To solve it I had to go to Project->Properties->Source and at the bottom put as Default output folder {project}/bin/classes.